# Makefile error compiling LZMA on Mac OSX

Tags: compilation, makefile, lzma

I've downloaded the latest [**LZMA SDK**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/LZMA%20SDK/lzma922.tar.bz2/download) and I'm trying to compile it on Mac OSX, although get an error with any of the makefiles included in the tar ball. Here's the error with *any* makefile I try and run:

```
/lzma922/C/Util/Lzma/

# make

makefile:<#>: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Any help would be appreciated — thanks!

Comment: did you manage to compile it on OS X. I've got the same problem. would appreciate it if you tell did you overcome the problem. thanks